# Handle Message in SOAP Message handler not invoked

Tags: spring-boot, soap, cxf

I am working on springboot application having soap serives implemented using apache-cxf. I have implemented SOAPHandler methods to handle soap message and fault. While invoking soap service from client handleMessage() is not called.

```
    //custom class implementing SOAPHandler
    public final class JaxWsLoggingHandler implements 
        SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

       //this method will be called when server receives soap request
       @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
            SOAPMessage message = context.getMessage();
       }

       //this will be called when server throws error
       @Override
        public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
            SOAPMessage message = context.getMessage();
           return true;
        }

       @Override
        public void close(MessageContext context) {

        }
       @Override
       public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
        System.out.println("Inside getHeaders");
          return Collections.emptySet();
       }
 }
```

I expect handleMessage() to be called when invoking soap service from client, but getHeaders() alone get called.
It is working fine as expected without spring boot